# C# How to copy something in a row

Tags: c#, regex

I'm want to make something like "Copy Links",

For example the file listed in:

```
this is example http://stackoverflow.com and nothing more.
and another way http://www.google.com.
```

How to keep only the URLs? like:

```
 http://stackoverflow.com
 http://www.google.com
```

I know something like this:

```
MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(str, "http.+?com", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

It's a good code? How can copy the result ^ to a text file?

Please give me example for that.

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of C# do you want? Surely you're not using 2-4 simultaneously, in the same line of code. Parsing out things that look like links is going to be very inaccurate, anyway.

Comment: URL regex test: http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex

Answer (score 3):

I would be a bit more stict

```
Protocol, domain name, page and CGI parameters are captured into backreferenes 1 through 4

\b((?#protocol)https?|ftp)://((?#domain)[-A-Z0-9.]+)((?#file)/[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?((?#parameters)\?[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?
```

or even

```
URL: RFC 3986
Validate if a string holds a URL as specified in RFC 3986.  Both absolute and relative URLs are supported. 


(# Scheme
 [a-z][a-z0-9+\-.]*:
 (# Authority & path
  //
  ([a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=]+@)?              # User
  ([a-z0-9\-._~%]+                            # Named host
  |\[[a-f0-9:.]+\]                            # IPv6 host
  |\[v[a-f0-9][a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:]+\])  # IPvFuture host
  (:[0-9]+)?                                  # Port
  (/[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)*/?          # Path
 |# Path without authority
  (/?[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+(/[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)*/?)?
 )
|# Relative URL (no scheme or authority)
 ([a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=@]+(/[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)*/?  # Relative path
 |(/[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)+/?)                            # Absolute path
)
# Query
(\?[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@/?]*)?
# Fragment
(\#[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@/?]*)?
```